# How to search for transaction where posting is yes in suitescript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have written a user event script to update posted transactions so I have to understand that the transaction (e.g. invoice) is posted.
How can I search this on suitescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are looking for `posting` filter (You can add the search columns that you want)

```
var transactions = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction', null, 
       [['posting', 'is', 'T'], 'and', ['mainline','is', 'T']);
```